# How manually commit transaction with Junit and Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit

I know it's not something new but I tried several approachs found and they didn't work.
I've a simple Junit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class LicensePlateTests {

@Autowired
private LicensePlateRepository licensePlateRepository;

@Autowired
private CountryRepository countryRepository;

@Before
public void setup() {
    TestTransaction.start();
    Country country = new Country();
    country.setName("Italy");
    country.setIsoCode("IT");
    countryRepository.save(country);

    assertEquals(1, countryRepository.count());
}

@Test
public void saveLicensePlateAndChangeCheckAudited() {
        assertEquals(1, countryRepository.count());
        LicensePlate plate = new LicensePlate();
        plate.setLicensePlate("AA123BB");
        plate.setEngineEuroLevel(3);
        plate.setCoutry(countryRepository.findFirstByOrderByIdAsc());
        plate = licensePlateRepository.save(plate);             

        assertEquals(1, licensePlateRepository.count());

        plate.setEngineEuroLevel(5);
        plate = licensePlateRepository.save(plate);     

        //always 1 plate
        assertEquals(1, licensePlateRepository.count());

        //different version number
        assertEquals(2, plate.getVersion().intValue());

    }
}
```

This test case fails because the version number remains 1.

What I'm doing could seem a bit strange but this test is just partial and is done because I'm using @Audited annotation on several properties inside my bean to track changes.
What I was trying to do here is checking if the version number is incremented after a change. I know that @Transactional commit the transaction just at the end of the method and so this explains why my method fails.

What I was looking for is a way to make several commits in the same test method but at the same time preserving the visibilily of the transaction from the @Before method to the end of the test case.

Some best practice to follow?

===============================================================

I think I've solved my problem. I'm not sure my solution is a best practice and it's good, so I don't post it as reply. I think it could be useful so this is the complete class (I took inspiration from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/envers/repository/support/RepositoryIntegrationTests.java)

```
     @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
public class LicensePlateAuditableTests {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private LicensePlateRepository licensePlateRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        licensePlateRepository.deleteAll();
        countryRepository.deleteAll();

        Country country = new Country();
        country.setName("Italy");
        country.setIsoCode("IT");
        countryRepository.save(country);        
    }



    @Test
    public void saveLicensePlateAndChangeCheckAudited() {
        assertEquals(1, countryRepository.count());

        LicensePlate plate = new LicensePlate();
        plate.setLicensePlate("AA123BB");
        plate.setEngineEuroLevel(3);
        plate.setCoutry(countryRepository.findFirstByOrderByIdAsc());
        plate = licensePlateRepository.save(plate);

        // First version number is 1
        assertEquals(1, plate.getVersion());

        // Changing some auditable data
        plate.setEngineEuroLevel(5);
        plate.setLicensePlate("AA956BB");
        plate = licensePlateRepository.save(plate);

        // different version number
        assertEquals(2, plate.getVersion());

        // I should have 2 revisions
        assertEquals(2, licensePlateRepository.findRevisions(plate.getId()).getContent().size());

        Revisions<Integer, LicensePlate> revisions = licensePlateRepository.findRevisions(plate.getId());

        int i = 1;
        for (Revision<Integer, LicensePlate> rev : revisions.getContent()) {
            if (i == 1) {
                // At the beginning the engine level was 3
                assertEquals(3, rev.getEntity().getEngineEuroLevel());
                // At the beginning the place number was AA123BB
                assertEquals("AA123BB", rev.getEntity().getLicensePlate());
            }

            if (i == 2) {
                // Then the engine level became 5
                assertEquals(5, rev.getEntity().getEngineEuroLevel());
                // Then the license plate number became AA956BB
                assertEquals("AA956BB", rev.getEntity().getLicensePlate());
            }
            i++;
        }

        // Check if the entry in the database has updated data
        assertEquals(5, licensePlateRepository.findOne(plate.getId()).getEngineEuroLevel());
        assertEquals("AA956BB", licensePlateRepository.findOne(plate.getId()).getLicensePlate());
    }
```

Comment: I don't think JUnit tests should commit transactions.  It seems more appropriate to execute, verify, and roll them back when you're done.  Leave the database in the same state it was in when the test was first run.

Comment: @duffymo you right, but I would need to simulate several operation in different transactions on the same object. I think from my last update you can understand the idea I want to reach.

Comment: it's strange when you do first end transaction and the start , it's difficult to understand if somebody supports you test. also why do you create and persist object and do assert for it ? setup section - for setup (you can create object and use in in every test, but county belongs only for setup emthod and not vivible in tests method). without assert in your case. i see you use it in         plate.setCoutry(countryRepository.findFirstByOrderByIdAsc());
but avoit assert in setup section . you do same assert in the begining of every method.

Comment: also method saveLicensePlateAndChangeCheckAudited do alot of check. try to follow princeple one test method test on thing     , just remarks for test design

Comment: @sbjavateam thanks for your advice. I changed again my code following an example of test found in spring-data-envers repository. About the problem of checking several things: should I split the method saveLicensePlateAndChangeCheckAudited in several methods, one for each assert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your comments in test method give you hints how many tests method should be.
Just advice : you should follow on one name convention for tests method that is appropriate for you and your team. In my projects I get used to start test method's name with 'check' , 'verify'... and explaine use case that I check in method.
something like this (just idea as you didn't show real classes) also I tried to show how test's method name might looks like :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
public class LicensePlateAuditableTests {
private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

@Autowired
private LicensePlateRepository licensePlateRepository;

@Autowired
private CountryRepository countryRepository;

private LicensePlate plate;
private final String PLATE_NUMBER_FIRST = "AA123BB";
private final String PLATE_NUMBER_SECOND = "AA956BB";
private int ENGINE_EURO_LEVEL_FIRST = 3;
private int ENGINE_EURO_LEVEL_SECOND = 3;

@Before
public void setup() {
    licensePlateRepository.deleteAll();
    countryRepository.deleteAll();

    Country country = new Country();
    country.setName("Italy");
    country.setIsoCode("IT");
    countryRepository.save(country);
}

@Test
public void checkThatVersionIsOneAfterCreateLicensePlate() {
    //given
    plate = createLicensePlateWithDefaultCountry(PLATE_NUMBER_FIRST, ENGINE_EURO_LEVEL_FIRST);
    //when
    plate = licensePlateRepository.save(plate);
    //then
    // First version number is  -- comment : if you want to comment something , include it into assert fail message
    assertEquals("version should be 1 for just created LicensePlate ", 1, plate.getVersion());
}

@Test
public void check_that_version_is_increased_when_changing_some_auditable_data() {
    //given
    plate = createLicensePlateWithDefaultCountry(PLATE_NUMBER_FIRST, ENGINE_EURO_LEVEL_FIRST);
    plate = licensePlateRepository.save(plate);
    //when
    setPlateEngineEuroLevelAndLicensePlate(PLATE_NUMBER_SECOND,ENGINE_EURO_LEVEL_SECOND);
    plate = licensePlateRepository.save(plate);
    //then
    assertEquals("version should be increased when Changing some auditable data",2, plate.getVersion());

    // Check if the entry in the database has updated data
    LicensePlate plateInDB = licensePlateRepository.findOne(plate.getId());
    assertNotNull(".. explanation..." , plateInDB);
    assertPlateNumberAndEngineEuroLevelAsInPlate(PLATE_NUMBER_SECOND , ENGINE_EURO_LEVEL_SECOND, plateInDB);
}

@Test
public void verify_revisions_after_two_changes() {
    //given
    plate = createLicensePlateWithDefaultCountry(PLATE_NUMBER_FIRST, ENGINE_EURO_LEVEL_FIRST);
    plate = licensePlateRepository.save(plate);
    //when
    setPlateEngineEuroLevelAndLicensePlate(PLATE_NUMBER_SECOND,ENGINE_EURO_LEVEL_SECOND);
    plate = licensePlateRepository.save(plate);
    //then
    Revisions<Integer, LicensePlate> revisions = licensePlateRepository.findRevisions(plate.getId());

    assertNotNull(".....something like : revisions should be found...." ,revisions);
    assertNotNull(".....something like : revisions.getContent should be found...." ,revisions.getContent());
    assertFalse(" should be present content for revisions " ,  revisions.getContent().isEmpty());
    assertEquals("I should have 2 revisions" ,2, revisions.getContent().size());

    //!!!! if you sure about order !!!!
    Revision<Integer, LicensePlate> revFirst = revisions.getContent().get(0);
    Revision<Integer, LicensePlate> revSecond = revisions.getContent().get(1);

    assertPlateNumberAndEngineEuroLevelAsInPlate(PLATE_NUMBER_FIRST, ENGINE_EURO_LEVEL_FIRST, revFirst.getEntity());
    assertPlateNumberAndEngineEuroLevelAsInPlate(PLATE_NUMBER_SECOND , ENGINE_EURO_LEVEL_SECOND, revSecond.getEntity());

}

private void assertPlateNumberAndEngineEuroLevelAsInPlate(String plateNumber , int engineEuroLevel , LicensePlate plate){
    assertEquals(engineEuroLevel, plate.getEngineEuroLevel());
    assertEquals(plateNumber , plate .getLicensePlate());
}

private LicensePlate createLicensePlateWithDefaultCountry(String plateNumber , int engineEuroLevel){
    LicensePlate plate = new LicensePlate();
    setPlateEngineEuroLevelAndLicensePlate(plateNumber , engineEuroLevel);
    plate.setCoutry(countryRepository.findFirstByOrderByIdAsc());
    return plate;
}

private void setPlateEngineEuroLevelAndLicensePlate(String plateNumber , int engineEuroLevel){
    plate.setEngineEuroLevel(engineEuroLevel);
    plate.setLicensePlate(plateNumber);
}
}
```